# Execute batch file after another batch file completes

Tags: batch-file, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call one batch file after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490549/how-to-call-one-batch-file-after-another)

I have a batch file coordinating the activity of two other batch file. How can I make it execute the second batch file only after the first bat file finishes execution (execute the sequentially). I do not care if the first batch file executes successfully or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [call](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) to continue the execution of the first file, like:

```
echo batch controller
call batch1.bat
call batch2.bat
echo batch controller running again
```

Comment: I don't think that's the question. There's a top-level batch file that's executing two secondary batch files sequentially.

Comment: @Jim ... it should work the way I posted ... where do you see the problem, here? I edited the example to use two batchfiles.

Comment: Yes, you're right that "call" needs to be used here.

Comment: Thanks for the useful site. def, something to add to my bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

They will execute sequentially naturally unless your first one is spawning processes without waiting. See START /WAIT for a way to start a process on the command line, but wait for it to finish before proceeding.