# windows batch file terminating prematurely

Tags: batch-file

I have a following batch file

```
echo Setting  visual studio 2010 environment variables
set VSPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
%VSPATH%\VC\vcvarsall.bat

echo Generating Service
```

the 'Generating Service' line never prints out, can someone point out how it should be done so batch file continues execution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023543/execute-batch-file-after-another-batch-file-completes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the CALL statement in front of your batch file

```
echo Setting  visual studio 2010 environment variables 
set VSPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" 
CALL %VSPATH%\VC\vcvarsall.bat 

echo Generating Service
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefix it with `start`:

```
echo Setting  visual studio 2010 environment variables
set VSPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
start %VSPATH%\VC\vcvarsall.bat

echo Generating Service
```

Answer (score 1):

use this if you want the vcvarsall.bat to run in the current window and not a separate one.

```
Call %VSPATH%\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```