# How to execute several batch commands in sequence

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a Windows XP batch script that sequentially performs something like the following:

```
@echo off
:: build everything
cd \workspace\project1
mvn clean install
cd ..\project2
mvn clean install

:: run some java file
cd \workspace\project3
java -jar somefile.jar
```

When I create a Batch script like this (following [these](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000738.htm) instructions), I still have the problem that the script stops doing something after the first

```
mvn clean install
```

and then displays the command line.
How can i execute all of these commands in sequence in one batch file?

I don't want to refer to other [files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023543/execute-batch-file-after-another-batch-file-completes), I want to do it in one file.

Comment: I was looking to write similar batch file for maven too !!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you invoke `mvn` command you never go back to your script again.

Try using the [`call`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) command e.g.:

```
call mvn clean install
```

This will invoke `mvn clean install` command and then return back to your script.

When you simply invoke `mvn` without `call` you actually invoke [`mvn.bat`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/components/tags/maven-2.0.8/maven-core/src/bin/mvn.bat) file and pass control to it.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use the `call` command on `mvn` (which seems to be another batch file?)

Like this:

```
@echo off
:: build everything
cd \workspace\project1
call mvn clean install
cd ..\project2
call mvn clean install

:: run some java file
cd \workspace\project3
java -jar somefile.jar
```

Source: google is your friend.