# Integrate Angular and Webpack in an ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, webpack

I am looking for a write up with steps i can follow to add Angular to an existing MVC application that lives in an area of my solution. I have found a write up that shows me how to add angular using a gulp.js file that pulls the necessary node_modules and transpiles my ts files into js files. I would like to do the same exact thing using webpack instead.

[image]

Currently my package.json looks like this.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "aspnet",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/common": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/core": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/forms": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/http": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/router": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/upgrade": "4.3.5",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.2",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
        "core-js": "2.5.0",
        "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
        "rxjs": "5.4.3",
        "zone.js": "0.8.16",
        "systemjs": "^0.20.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-tsc": "~1.3.2",
        "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.2",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2"
    }
}
```

**[This](http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/)** is the write up I followed that uses gulp and this works.

But i would much rather prefer using webpack instead of a gulp task.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I hope that can help you find the idea because our projects also need to integrate webpack and ASP.NET MVC together. Noted that it is my own proposal so that there might be a better way to do it. Below is what we do.

Check the [source code on Github](https://github.com/trungk18/mvc5-angular-webpack)

[image: module 1]

**1. Structure the project**

We separated our project into two folders: **Client and Server**. Those will be located in **mvc5-angular-webpack** folder and this folder will be committed to the repository

```
mvc5-angular-webpack/
├── Server/
│   ├── WebApplication/
│   │     ├── Controllers/
│   │     ├── Scripts/
│   │     ├── Web.config
│   │     ├── Many more folder and file...
│   │        
│   └── Web-Core.sln
│   
├── Client/
    ├── modules
    │     ├── angularModule-1/
    │     │      ├── main.ts
    │     │      ├── app.modules.ts
    │     │      ├── app.component.ts
    │     │      ├── Many more file...
    │     │
    │     ├── angularModule-2/
    │     │      ├── main.ts
    │     │      ├── app.modules.ts
    │     │      ├── app.component.ts
    │     │      ├── Many more file...
    │     ├── polyfill.ts
    │     ├── vendor.ts
    │
    └── build.bat
    └── npm-shrinkwrap.json
    └── package.json
    └── tsconfig.json
    └── tslint.json
    └── webpack.config.js
```

- In the **Server** folder, we added the MVC solution named `Web-Core.sln`
   and all the common library project is written in C#.
- In the **Client** folder only contains front-end related stuff. To build the front project, simply call the `build.bat`. I will talk about this file content later. Inside modules folder, our project will create each subfolder for each module.

Our website has some module still using server-side rendering with pure Razor. And there is some module written in client-side code with AngularJS and Angular.

**2. Configure `webpack`**

Assume that you configured all the `typescript` and `npm` already. Let see what I have inside `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const entryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'modules')
const corePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../Server/WebApplication/Scripts/ng2')
const module1 = `${entryPath}/angularModule-1`
const module2 = `${entryPath}/angularModule-2`

module.exports = (envOptions) => {
    envOptions = envOptions || {};

    const config = {
        entry: {
            'polyfills': `${entryPath}/polyfill.ts`,
            'vendors': `${entryPath}/vendor.ts`,
            'module1': `${module1}/main.ts`,
            'module2': `${module2}/main.ts`            
        },
        output: {
            path: corePath,
            filename: '[name].js',
            sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map"            
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    loader: 'raw-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'raw-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: ['vendors', 'polyfills']
            })
        ]
    }

    if (envOptions.MODE === 'prod') {
        config.plugins.push(
            new UglifyJsPlugin()
        )
    }

    return config;
}
```

So basically it will try to resolve the directory in an upper level and put all the compiled files to **Scripts/ng2** inside **Server** folder.

**3. Configure npm script**

After configured `webpack`, we will basically add some more script to run during the build process. Add the following code to `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --https --open",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:html": "webpack --config webpack-html-plugin.config.js --env.MODE=prod",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.MODE=prod"    
}
```

**4. Configure `build.bat`**

At the beginning of Angular 2 integration, we have created an empty web application project for front-end purpose and added this project as a dependency of our `WebApplication`. But our backend team later complained about how slow the front-end process take. Because they don't need the front-end project to build every time the `WebApplication` is being built.

The idea of the `build.bat` file is to manually run it to get the latest version of front-end code on their machine. Not every single time they run the project.

```
call npm install --production  --loglevel verbose
echo "Build Angular projects"
npm run build:prod
```

The `call` is to continue because some of the commands abort the command line. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673714/how-to-execute-several-batch-commands-in-sequence)

The script here is very simple. First, we run the npm install to restore all the necessary dependency. Then call `build:prod` as we defined on `package.json` before. Webpack will take care of bundle our Typescript code into three big JavaScript files as `vendors.js`, `polyfills.js` and `module1.js`.

Our team used Jenkins for deployment, so our dev ops just need to include to run the `build.bat` and we are all set. If you want to run it everytime your project was built, you can set it inside the pre-build or post-build event.

[image: pre-build and post-build]
[Image source](http://www.aaronstannard.com/visualstudio-pre-build-tasks/)

**5. Reference compiled JavaScript file in the view.**

Normally we will return only one view in an area as below. The `my-angular-app` is what we defined in `app.component.ts`

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ng2/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ng2/vendors.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ng2/module1.js"></script>

<my-angular-app>
    Loading...
</my-angular-app>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Module1()
{
    return View();
}
```

That is a bit drawback If we deploy to production. Because after the compiled JavaScript was updated, the browser sometimes still keep the old version of the file because of caching. We should have a mechanism to provide a unique name for the files after deployment. There are 3 options for us to do so.

**i. [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)**

If we work with pure front-end project, `webpack` provides [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to take care of it as below. Technically, It will automatically inject the JavaScript file into our view with the unique id.

[webpack-html-webpack-plugin.config.js](https://github.com/trungk18/mvc5-angular-webpack/blob/master/Client/webpack-html-plugin.config.js)

```
...
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const viewPath = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    "../Server/WebApplication/Views/Home"
  );
...
entry: {
    polyfills: `${entryPath}/polyfill.ts`,
    vendors: `${entryPath}/vendor.ts`,
    module1: `${module1}/main.ts`      
},
output: {
    path: corePath,
    filename: "[name].[hash].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].[hash].js.map"
}
....
plugins: [,
    ...,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: viewPath + "/loader.cshtml",
        filename: viewPath + "/Module1.cshtml",
        inject: false
    })
]
```

And in the same folder with the designated view, we created a cshtml file named `loader.cshtml`

[loader.cshtml](https://github.com/trungk18/mvc5-angular-webpack/blob/master/Server/WebApplication/Views/Home/loader.cshtml)

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>  
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>  
<% } %> 

<my-angular-app>
    Loading...
</my-angular-app>
```

And run the `npm run build:html` as defined on `package.json`. If it runs successfully, the result will look like that.

[image: build html plugin]

[image: network html plugin]

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Module 1";
}
<script src="../../Scripts/ng2/vendors.1470de344a0f2260b700.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ng2/vendors.1470de344a0f2260b700.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ng2/module1.1470de344a0f2260b700.js"></script>

<my-angular-app>Loading....</my-angular-app>
```

**ii. Defined your own JavaScript version**

In our ASP.NET MVC project is a bit different because we used more than one Angular app. So that we defined a version in the class and append it at the end of the file when loading the JS. By doing it, we will make sure the latest will be loaded into the browser. But it is out of this question context so I will not go further. Basically, It is gonna look like below code.

```
<script src="@string.Format("{0}?v={1}", "~/Scripts/ng2/polyfills.js", VersionHelper.CurrentVersion())</script>
<script src="@string.Format("{0}?v={1}", "~/Scripts/ng2/vendors.js", VersionHelper.CurrentVersion())</script>
<script src="@string.Format("{0}?v={1}", "~/Scripts/ng2/module1.js", VersionHelper.CurrentVersion())</script>
```

When serving it on browser, it will look like

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ng2/polyfills.js?v=1.1.0"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ng2/vendors.js?v=1.1.0"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ng2/module1.js?v=1.1.0"></script>
```

**iii. [ASP.NET Bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)**

At Zyllem, our team didn't use it because of our JavaScript files is configure inside the model and render it later to the view.

You can just open `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` in your project and config a bundle. Let say the name is `module1`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/module1").Include(
                "~/Scripts/ng2/polyfills.js",
                "~/Scripts/ng2/vendors.js"
                "~/Scripts/ng2/module1.js"));
```

And render inside the view by doing it.

Index.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/module1")
```

So that when serving on the browser, it will have the unique token at the end and it is different If you make any changes in the script bundle.

```
<script src="/bundles/module1?v=2PbUw0z_gh_Ocp_Vz13rdmmBSG6utLJAXm2lThxYAow1"></script>
```

If everything works fine, you will see the below screenshots.

[image: module 1]

[image: module 2]

---

**Update**

Add the repository on Github https://github.com/trungk18/mvc5-angular-webpack

Comment: This is a pretty good explanation.

Comment: @trungk18 This is a great explanation. I will give it a try.

Comment: Hope it is not too late, I have just created a repository https://github.com/trungk18/mvc5-angular-webpack. You can download and try. It could be easier as well.

Comment: @trungk18 hey I really wanted to award that bounty to you as you very much deserve it. I will make an effort to do so. I dont understand why these nerds would put my question on hold as this answer is very valuable and a lot of people could benefit from it.