# MVC with angular 7

Tags: c#, angular

I have been developing SSO App uses moves with c# and AngularJs and now I am adding one new project in my existing SSO app, but want to use Angular 7. so please let me know hot to use angular 7 and run this particular project from SSO app.

Comment: I recommend you this repo, https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-angular-universal

Comment: Hope this could help too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870611/integrate-angular-and-webpack-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application/47918737#47918737

Answer (score 0):

You already have an app running with C# and AngularJS. so let us call this as **App1**. Another app you want to create with Angular 7, let us call this **App2**.
Create **App2** ie Angular 7 as a normal angular app.

Now to implement SSO, there are certain things to keep in mind

1) You need to have a central login page. This page is responsible for central login as **App1** and **App2** wont be having separate login pages.

2) Use cookies to check existence of user in either of the Apps

3) You need to have logic implemented in all Apps (**App1**, **App2** and **central App)** to check for the cookie existence and navigate to the desired app.

A good example would be google.
When you are not logged in you are redirected to accounts.google.com (central Login). After login in, you visit any google products gmail(App1), youtube(App2) etc without login in separately.That's SSO and done through cross-domain cookie check.

This link will I think help you understand how SSO works.

https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/

So you create angular 7 as a normal angular 7 app and follow the SSO steps. You will be good to go.

Hope that helps