# How to call one batch file after another

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that i am testing, all i want to do is the following

```
CALL ping.bat
```

Then after that batch file has run i want to run another file:

```
CALL ping2.bat
```

Right now i have these two lines beside each other in a batch file the first batch file will fire successfully but the second one does not .  Any suggestions?

```
CALL ping.bat
CALL ping2.bat
```

Ping .bat is just:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Post your actual batch file. 'beside each other' doesn't work (and doesn't make a lot of sense as written).

Comment: Perhaps the first call to ping.bat is not actually completing?

Comment: Can you post Ping.bat as well? I'm suspecting @Joey is right, and Ping.bat either has an exit or launches another batch file without CALL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 18):

Check that you don't have `exit` somewhere in the first batch. Some people habitually use that to jump out of a batch file which is not the proper way to exit a batch (`exit /b` or `goto :eof` is).

Another option is that you might call another batch in the first one *without* `call`.

Answer (score 6):

There's a chance your `ping.bat` is simply calling itself, if its contents is merely `ping 127.0.0.1`, as you say.

I would append `.exe` after `ping` to make things sure.

As *jeb* has by all means justly suggested, choosing a different name for your batch file is an even better solution.

Comment: +1 Good point (I didn't see the obvious), but perhaps it's a bad idea to name it ping.bat, it should be named `MyPing.bat` or something else

Answer (score 5):

Assume you have 3 batch files.

1. ping1.bat which has the content ping 127.0.0.1
2. ping2.bat which has the content ping 127.0.0.1
3. ping3.bat which has the below two lines
   call ping1.bat
   call ping2.bat

If you have all the three batch files in a single folder,(lets say under C:\NewFolder)
then if you double click ping3.bat, you won't get any error for sure.

Note: If you don't want to wait for the first command to complete, then use start keyword which just initiate the process and proceed with the next line in the batch file, whereas call 
will do it sequentially(comes to next line only after the current process completes , start allows parallelism)
To do it parallel use the below two lines of code in the ping3.bat:

start ping1.bat
start ping2.bat

Answer (score 2):

don't call the file  you are calling from the batch the same name as the command you are trying to invoke...renamed to gnip.bat and works fine

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you wanted to do here, but I assume that you wanted to do this:

1. run FIRST.bat
2. from FIRST.bat you wish to call SECOND.bat
3. While SECOND.bat is executing, FIRST.bat should remain paused
4. After SECOND.bat finishes its execution, FIRST.bat should resume and call THIRD.bat

In that case, from your actual batch file, you should start **ping.bat** and **ping2.bat** like this:

```
::some code here
start /wait ping.bat
start /wait ping2.bat
::some code here
```

Then in both **ping.bat** and **ping2.bat** the last line should be **exit**. Their code should look like this:

```
::some code here, might be ping 127.0.0.1
exit
```

So now your actual batch file will start **ping.bat** and it will wait for it to finish (exit). Once the **ping.bat** closes, your actual batch file will go to the next line and it will start **ping2.bat** etc.

Answer (score 0):

The ping command acts differently on different operating systems.  Try forcing the ping command to stop after a few echo requests with a -n switch.

ping -n 4 127.0.0.1