# Need assistence merging two batch files (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, copy, exe

So now i have 2 .bat files. one copies some file if it was updated **( robocopy C:\location C:\destination)** and another one that executes a some kind of .exe file **(start c:\BAT\fraps.exe)** , now what i need is maybe a one file, so that WHEN a file was copied using "robocopy" the executive file would run automaticaly. So maybe there is a way to merge them into one or smth.

Comment: Why can't you create a new batch file with all the commands in batch1 then followed by all commands in batch2?  Or a separate batch file to call batch1 then batch2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errorlevels are set by robocopy: errorlevel 1 means that a file was successfully copied.

```
robocopy C:\location C:\destination
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 start c:\BAT\fraps.exe
```

**Here is proof of concept code - following extended comments:**

```
@echo off
md test1
:loop
>test1\testfile.txt echo aaa
robocopy test1 test2
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 pause
del test1\testfile.txt
goto :loop
```

Comment: It sometime calls the exe sometimes doesn't

Comment: replace `start c:\BAT\fraps.exe` with `pause` and test it.  It it also doesn't pause when you expect it to, then the problem is that there are no files being copied.

Comment: It does copy the files new content, but doesn't pause or start the exe file

Comment: It it doesn't pause or start the exe, and robocopy is actually running and you see the screen output from robocopy running, then robocopy is not setting the errorlevel.  That is either due to the version of robocopy you are using being outdated or simply because the files really are not being copied.  If you place `pause` on the line directly after the robocopy command then you will see the robocopy summary on the screen and it will show you when files are copied and how many.  Triple check it.

Comment: I created all new folders, bat files, and all that suff, but it still only copies the files without launching the .exe. And one more thing Launching  separate batch files, (one runs exe, other does the copy ) everything goes well. Maybe the syntax for calling .exe IF the copying was performed is wrong?

Comment: Did you check the robocopy summary screens?

Comment: Yes, Files copied 1 ( i only have one .txt in there)

Comment: Robocopy will not copy the same file a second time.

Comment: i always change the text in it.

Comment: I can't see what you are doing and there is a flaw in your methodology.

Comment: I did, and it works.  I added the test code to my answer for you to try.

Comment: should it work if i copy paste all of it without changing anything?

Comment: For so freaking reason it does work :D, even without all those echo, md test and del.
EDIT: FOUND A BUG. When the two folders and a bat file are all on desktop it works. when two folders are in C: and bat file on desktop, exe file doesnt launch :D

Comment: So there is some issues with directories, when files and folders are not in the same place or some shit.

Answer (score 0):

Use /WAIT option, when the application is stared then it will wait until it terminates.

Use /B option, when application is started then it will not create a new window.

Example:

`start /wait Command CALL D:\YourFirstScript.bat`

`start /wait program.exe`

`start /wait Command CALL X:\YourSecondScript.bat`

It's a good idea to print a message before and after.

Example:

`ECHO Starting program.`

`start /wait program.exe`

`ECHO Finished.`

See below link for more details.

[How do I launch multiple batch files from one batch file with dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994250/how-do-i-launch-multiple-batch-files-from-one-batch-file-with-dependency)

Note: When you run script as administrator then you need to set full path as the default is set to "C:\Windows\System32".
The easiest way to set is

`start %~dp0Directory\program.exe`

See for details about "%~dp0" here
[What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

This is my first post and I hope that this will help you.

Comment: First of all. i need it to run like 24 hours a day, so when i did a loop (though maybe my loops is terrible) i had to unplug my pc cause there was too many windows popping up. Second of all it does copy the file, but does not start the exe file

Comment: To run 24/7, you need to schedule the script. What type of loop you're running in script?.
Check the error mentioned by _foxidrive_. May be there is a permission issue, run script as administrator.

Comment: Your script just doesn't work. it pops two windows, but doesn't prompt to execute the .exe

Comment: One thing more, when you run script as administrator then you need to set full path as default is set to "C:\Windows\System32". The easiest way is this.
`start %~dp0\Directory\program.exe`
Have you read the line about "New Window?"

See for details about "%~dp0" here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work